# How to know where a method is called in Java using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

There is a method in one of my java packages. How can I know where this method is used/called in other packages? I tried CTRL+H and CTR+SHIFT+G. But both didn't work for that.

I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: including calls in other libraries?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Sam I am using Eclipse. yes, including other libraries.

Comment: @PalakKharbanda you should understand that that is likely not possible

Comment: @Stultuske and what about other packages (exclude libraries)?

Comment: have you tried ALT + CTRL + H ?